# Stack smashing detected - from C to assembly

Tags: c, assembly, coredump, stack-smash

I'm trying to translate from C to assembly two functions, one that sort an array of index and one that find the minimum number starting from an index. When I run the program it works , the new array is sorted but at the end it gives me this error

```
1 2 3 3 4 6 7
*** stack smashing detected ***: ./invidia terminated
Annullato (core dump creato)
```

this is my .c file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int* sort(int* v, int dim);
int min(int v[], int dim, int t);
int main(){
    int v[] = {1,3,2,4,6,7,3};
    int dim = 7,i;
    int *c = sort(v,dim);
    for (i = 0; i<dim; i++)
         printf("%d ", c[i]);
    return 0;
}

/*int* sort(int* v, int dim){
    int i,j=0,t;
    int mino,temp;
    for (t = 0; t<dim; t++){
        for(i=t;i<dim;i++){
            mino = min (v,dim,t); <- min number from index t
            if (v[i]==mino){
                temp = v[j];
                v[j] = v[i];
                v[i] = temp;
                j++;
                break;  
            }   
        }
    }
    return v;


}
int min(int v[], int dim, int t){
    int i, min = 1000;
    for (i=t; i<dim;i++)
        if (v[i]<min)
            min = v[i];

    return min;

}
*/
```

and my .s file

```
.globl sort
sort:       #v->ebx dim-> esi i->edi, j->ecx t->edx, mino->eax, temp ->ebp
        pushl %ebx
        pushl %esi
        pushl %edi
        pushl %ebp
        subl $32, %esp
        movl 52(%esp), %ebx
        movl 56(%esp), %esi
        movl $0, %edi
        movl $0, %ecx
        movl $0, %eax
        movl $0, %edx
        movl $0, %ebp
FOR1:
        cmpl %esi, %edx
        jge EXIT
        movl %edx, %edi
FOR2:

        cmpl %esi, %edi
        jge EXIT2
        movl %ebx, (%esp)
        movl %esi, 4(%esp)
        movl %edx, 8(%esp)
        movl %ebx, 12(%esp)
        movl %eax, 16(%esp)
        movl %ecx, 20(%esp)
        movl %edx, 24(%esp)
        call min
        movl 12(%esp), %ebx
        movl 20(%esp), %ecx
        movl 24(%esp), %edx
        cmpl (%ebx, %edi, 4), %eax
        jne PSEUDOEND
        movl (%ebx, %ecx, 4), %ebp
        movl %esi, 12(%esp)
        movl (%ebx, %edi, 4), %esi
        movl %esi, (%ebx, %ecx, 4)
        movl %ebp, (%ebx, %edi, 4)
        movl 12(%esp), %esi
        incl %ecx
        incl %edx
        jmp FOR1

PSEUDOEND: 
        incl %edi
        jmp FOR2
EXIT:
        movl %ebx, %eax
        popl %ebp
        popl %edi
        popl %esi
        popl %ebx
        addl $32, %esp
        ret

EXIT2:
        incl %edx
        jmp FOR1

.globl min
min:
        movl 4(%esp), %ecx
        movl 8(%esp), %edx
        movl 12(%esp), %ebx
        movl $1000, %eax
FOR:
        cmpl %edx, %ebx
        jge END
        cmpl %eax, (%ecx, %ebx, 4)
        cmovl (%ecx, %ebx, 4), %eax
        incl %ebx
        jmp FOR
END:

        ret
```

to compile I use

```
gcc -m32 filename.c filename.s -o filename
```

I don't think that the problem is in the assembly translation because it prints correctly the new array. What could be the problem?

Comment: One obvious issue is that you have the `addl $32, %esp` at the wrong place.

Comment: yes, you're right, I'm sorry for this dumb question

Comment: regarding these two lines:`    int *c = malloc(sizeof(int)*dim); c = sort(v,dim);`  1) always check the returned value from `malloc()` to assure the operation was successful 2) this is a major memory leak because: after acquiring a pointer to allocated memory into the 'c' variable, overlays that pointer with the returned value from `sort()`  Suggest fixing the C code before trying to convert to assembly

Comment: I changed the mainfile , but it works also with the old main. Thanks for the tips

Comment: the complexity of the code can be greatly reduced by having `min()` return the index into the 'v[]' array rather than the contents.  Then the `sort()` could simply swap the 'current lowest index contents with the v[min()] contents rather than having to iterate over the whole rest of the array again and again and again.  There will be an issue when the 'v[]' contains duplicate values as the one selected by `min()` may not be the one actually swapped in the `sort()` function

Comment: the `sort()` algorithm sorts "in place" so no need for the call to malloc() nor the variable 'c'

Comment: there is no need for the variable 'dim' nor the variable 'i' in the main function.  any usage of 'dim' can be replaced with: `sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0]`

Comment: the call to `printf()` is very inflexable. suggest: `for(size_t i=0; i< (sizeof(v)/sizeof(v[0]);; i++) { printf(  "%d ", v[i] ); } printf( "\n");